# Module augmentation does not need to be imported?

Tags: typescript

I have a module like this:

```
// File: modules/cat.ts
export class Cat {
    greet(): void { console.log('hi...'); }
}
```

And then I augment that module like this:

```
// File: modules/run.ts
import {Cat} from './cat';

declare module './cat' {
    interface Cat {
        run();
    }
}

Cat.prototype.run = function() {
    console.log('I can run..');
}
```

Then I try to use that two modules like this:

```
// File: modules/index.ts
import {Cat} from './cat';
// ./run is not imported

let cat = new Cat();
cat.greet(); // Print 'hi...'
cat.run(); // Should not this line cause an error?
```

Bellow is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    }
}
```

All the code above can be compiled successfully. But of course, when I ran 'node modules/index.js', I got en error: cat.run is not a function. Because I did not import modules/run.ts into modules/index.ts.

My question is, why TypeScript's compiler should let 'cat.run()' pass the compilation when modules/run.ts is not imported into modules/index.ts?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple output files, the TypeScript compiler does not attempt to keep track of which files are loaded in what order in order to catch errors like this.  (It does catch simple cases of using something before defining it in the same output file.)  My understanding is this is because there would be too many false positive errors, particularly when you are compiling a library of files that other code will be loading in an unknown order.